# JSON Encode charset issue

Tags: javascript, php

I am having some character encoding issues with my json_encode function:

I have a `javascript variable` which stores a string of text for me:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 postQuote = <?php echo json_encode($post['post_text']); ?>
</script>
```

`$post['post_text']` is taken from the MySQL database, where it shows correctly. If I just print out `$post['post_text']` there will be no problem in the encoding.

Now, the string can example be:

```
You're doing great today? That's perfect.
```

Now the `postQuote` will output:

```
You&amp;#039;re doing great today? That&amp;#039;s perfect
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please try `json_encode(…, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` or `json_encode(…, 0)`.

Comment: @Kay it changes nothing..

Comment: If you see the result with browser, then having `You&amp;#039;re doing great today? That&amp;#039;s perfect` shouldn't be a problem, since you will see: `You're doing great today? That's perfect.` Isn't that the case?

Comment: The outputted text is "You&amp;#039;re" and not "You're" - that's the issue.

Comment: Chances are that `$post['post_text']` already contains this encoding, does it?

Comment: It doesn't. It only shows it like that, whenever I add the json_encode